# What does the following way of declaring an array mean?

Tags: java

```
Object[] args = new Object[0];
```

I came across this code in my code base while debugging.

Somewhere later there is another statement like this:

```
args = new Object[10] ;
```

Questions :

1. Why would some one want to initialize an array of length zero?
2. Why cant the code just be: `Object[] args` and then when the time comes `args = new Object[10]`. Is there any significance in creating an array of length zero?

Comment: Actually what I want to ask is, why would some one want to initialize an array of length zero? Why cant the code just be: `Object[] args` and then when the time comes `args = new Object[10]`. Is there any significance in creating an array of length zero?

Answer (score 2):

It just creates array of size 0.  Most likely done to prevent NullPointerException somewhere. Next assignment discards previous array and assigns new one of size 10 to the same variable.

Answer (score 1):

It's a canonical object array declaration and initialization. The first line initializes the `args` variable with a new array of 0 element. The second one reinitializes the variable with a new array of 10 elements.

Answer (score 1):

That's the decleration of an empty array. It's useful if you don't want to check for null values before you enter for or plain foreach loops.

Answer (score 0):

This creates an array Object, with zero slots.

```
Object[] args = new Object[0];
```

This then sets args to an array of Object with 10 holders, which will all be blank until you put something in them.

```
args = new Object[10] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object[]` is an **object** of "array of Objects" in Java. Arrays are special objects in Java.
So you are assigning **args** to another object, which has initially null values on its indexes.

> "Is there any significance in creating an array of length zero?"

- No, it is just for initializing the **args** variable which may prevent you from some
  compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0):

new Object[0] is an empty array of objects.

it's like initializing an int to zero before you need it. The initial value is discarded on the second assignment `args = new Object[10] ;`

Answer (score 0):

Usually this type of coding is done when, you don't know the actual size of array (args in your case) while you're initializing it. The size of the array is decided at run time. That's why in initialization it's size is kept 0. Later on, in programming, when you come to know about the actual size of array it is re-initialized.

Comment: Why cant the code just be: `Object[] args` and then when the time comes `args = new Object[10]`. Is there any particular significance in creating an array of length zero?

Comment: @PoornimaPrakash Think about the following code: `Object[] args = new Object[0]; if(args.length == 0) {/*other code*/ args = new Object[10] ;
}`

Comment: @PoornimaPrakash This is just an example. Dig into your program. There should be some requirement of this kind. And if there is no such requirement, it might be _poor_ coding.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is my shot at how this could be useful:

When you want to use for loop like this:

```
for(Object arg:args){
    // do something with arg
}
```

And you don't initialize it before hand, the compiler will give you an error saying args might not have been initialized.

But, if you initialize args to null, you get null pointer exception.

Instead, if it is `new Object[0]`, args.length = 0, args is not null, the loop rightly won't be executed even once.

Answer (score 0):

With empty arrays you can safely iterate over arrays using advanced for loop. And you don't have to check for null.

```
     Object[] array = new Object[0];
     for(Object arg:array)
     {
         //It never enters here
     }
```

So when next time you assign it with `Object[] array = new Object[10]` this loop can iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

It's just defensive coding, possibly unnecessary. The same kind of thinking often seems to lead to this:

```
String line = "";
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
{
  // ...
}
```

which is definitely unnecessary.